# Read and rewrite the URL in angular 1 app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a php framework that handles the routes. One of this routes is set to render an index.html that runs an Angular app:

```
URL                      My server file system
mysite.com/a/:id  --->   somewhere/index.html
```

The parameter *id* is needed in the Angular app that uses a route like this: /#/app/:id/section1.

How can the angular app read the id and rewrite the url to go from:
`mysite.com/a/:id` to `mysite.com/a/#/app/:id/section1`

**Angular routing**

```
$stateProvider

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: '/_/lno_admin_panel_v2/templates/login.html',
        controller: 'login'
    })

    .state('app', {
        url: '/app/:listId',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '/_/lno_admin_panel_v2/templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'menu'
    })

    .state('app.list', {
        url: '/weddingList',
        views: {
            sectionHolder: {
                templateUrl: '/_/lno_admin_panel_v2/templates/wedding-list.html',
                controller: 'weddingList'
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide your AngularJS routing file?

Comment: @Mistalis check the edit